# Which depth-sensor camera supports OpenNI?

Tags: point-cloud-library, openni

Are there any depth-sensor cameras beside kinect that supports OpenNI? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 lts.

Answer (score 0):

- ASUS Xtion (still available)
- PrimeSense Carmine
- Microsoft Kinect
- Occipital Structure (still available)

See also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PrimeSense

Answer (score 0):

There are also OpenNI drivers for Microsoft's Kinect v2: [one using the official SDK](https://github.com/occipital/OpenNI2/tree/kinect2/Source/Drivers/Kinect2) (which of course only works on Windows 8 or later), and [one using libfreenect2](https://github.com/OpenKinect/libfreenect2/pull/302) (which should work on Ubuntu 14.04).

Additionally, it's not too hard to write your own OpenNI driver for whatever sensor you want to use.